# Searching Netapp Network Share in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, netapp

Windows 7 famously does not do what its predecessor, Windows XP, did very well, index and search network drives! Sometimes, the logic of MS isd absolutely baffling. 
That siad, I am trying to find some solution to the issue, which is made more complicated by the fact that we are using a Netapp FAS 2020 as a CIFS fileserver. 
I know some of the solutions to the Windows 7 search index issue revolve around having a Search Service installed on a Windows 2008 server and then adding that server sahre to the library on the Windows 7 workstation. Is it possible to accomplish this in any way with a CIFS share on a Netapp filer?

Answer (score 1):

As a work around, can you use a different "Search" application? I used to use Google Desktop for this a ways back.

Comment: After some searching, it doesn't appear there is a good solution to this. :(

Comment: I wish there was a decent solution to this. I can do without the search. Don't want that load with 500+ users on my NetApp anyway, but can't configure libraries onto network-drives either which is real stupid if you want to encourage users to store their data on the net in stead of on the local HD.